# What's the most simple way to make all negative elements of a matrix to 0 in DolphinDB database?

Tags: dolphindb

For this specific question, I use (x+abs(x))\2. But is there a more straightforward and more general way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
a=reshape(-5 .. 4, 5:2)
each(x->iif(x<0, 0, x), a)
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some explanation as to how this solves the problem. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/25005785)